# C++ run program in background Windows 10

Tags: c++, winapi, background, windows-10

I am trying to run an executable in background written in C++ in Windows 10. The program does not have any GUI. I tried this

```
window = FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL);
ShowWindow(window,0);
```

But although it does work on Windows 7 and opens and instantly closes the console, and the executable runs in background, on Windows 10 it opens a console and the console stays open. If I run the .exe with `run /B main.exe` I have to keep the console open in order for the program to keep running, and if I close the cmd console execution stops.

Is there a way to programatically run the file in background? I am aware that I can run it in background using vbscript, but I would like to avoid that.

Comment: You could explicitly [create a process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) for the application. Unless it contains code to explicitly display the console window, it shouldn't be shown IIRC.

Comment: But that would mean having to write 2 programs, right? As far as I have read in the docs, the input parameters for `createprocessa` requires me to give the path to the executable. I would like to have it all in one single program, both the option to run in background as well as the rest of the main program.

Comment: So you have one program, which executes itself? Doesn't matter, you can still use `CreateProcess` to execute *any* program you have the path to, including itself. Or (not really knowing the problem you're attempting to solve) perhaps what you really want is to use *threads* to run some parts of your program in the "background"?

Comment: `CreateProcess()` has flags to hide the process it spawns. If you spawn a console app, you can tell it to hide the console window that is created. You don't need to hunt for the window afterwards and hide it manually

Comment: @Hamperfait It works for me on Windows 10 that close the console window and running in background. Please check return value of `FindWindowA` and `ShowWindow` function to make sure execution success.

Comment: @Hamperfait Did you try the FreeConsole()? The console disappears if I start it without the debugger -- remains visible when started from Visual Studio. So it should do the job. I have only a win10 -- so I don't know the behavior on others..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With FreeConsole() you can detach a process from the console window -- that worked for me:

```
int main() 
{
   FreeConsole();
   while (1) ::Sleep(1000);
   return 0;
}
```

For detailed description see also the [related Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/freeconsole)

Comment: Can you explain better the answer and source code, thanks

Comment: I added a link to the microsoft doc -- check the function's doc for further reading.

Comment: @LXG: The documentation cited links to [AttachConsole](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/attachconsole), which explains "...A console is closed when the last process attached to it terminates or calls FreeConsole"